# How to disable extra screensharing / screenshoting permission requests?

Tags: screenshot

Recently, screensharing and screenshotting on my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS started behaving differently when sharing my screen using Google Meet on Chrome, or KSnip to take screenshots.

How do I give permission to apps (any app!) to take a screenshot without extra permissions?

What was once a reasonably smooth experience has turned into a nightmare. Every time I try to share an entire screen with Google Meet, I have to first click through an approval for Google Meet to grab a screenshot of my screens for displaying the thumbnails in the selector. This forces me to choose between two identically named monitors (Llama 23" or Llama 23"). Then once I select which screen I have to grant approval again. Since I often pick the "wrong" Llama 23, I generally have to repeat the process several times.

I spend a lot of time giving remote training to developers on our team or to our users, so this is bringing me to tears. (Yes, sharing Chrome tabs is easier, but that doesn't help when trying to share IntelliJ)

KSnip is the same, but worse. I use Ksnip alot for documentation, and two months (?) it was perfect. Now, I can only take a screenshot through something called a "Screenshot Portal", which requires a two second delay before taking a screenshot of the ENTIRE screen, asking my permission to share it with "the requesting application". At which point I have to choose Options, click "Select an area to grab", click "Take screenshot", and THEN give permission to share AGAIN. This used to be a **one click operation**.